# Customizing Bootstrap 5 with the @use Keyword

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I want to customize Bootstrap 5 in my custom.scss but I dont want to use @import statement because its deprecated and If there's better alternative, I will use it. I use Bootstrap npm starter template.

This is the usual customization with @import which requires you to assign variable before @import

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But I want to know how I can replace the above with **@use**, I tried this but didnt work:

```
// Your variable overrides
@use "/bootstrap/scss/variables"
variables.$body-bg = #222;
```

As far as I understand, I dont need to **assign variables before the @use** and dont need the !default while assigning my value.I dont know why Bootstrap 5 document still recommends using @import in sass file.

Comment: What makes you think that `@import` is deprecated?

Comment: Sure, the SASS curators warn that **eventually** this will be deprecated, but BS relies on the *global* nature of the `@import` directive.

Comment: 'import' not deprecated actually, NOT recommended. The main difference is how they handle members. 'import' makes everything globally accessible in the target file. This enables an endless chain of imported files where it's difficult to trace where your variables and mixins are coming from. It also allows for overlap and makes it difficult to trace back why your perfect css breaks. This is a problem especially with complex file structures and projects with multiple contributors and global libraries, which is why 'import' is no longer recommended by Sass.

Comment: but I hope u answer the real question/problem in my post. How to "use" in custom scss file and change default bootstrap theme.

Comment: but that's just the thing - BS will not work with `@use` ... the `_variables.scss` use needs to `@include` the `_functions.scss` ... if you `@use functions` then `variables` would have needed to be written in dot notation (i.e., `functions._assert-ascending()`) .. and it isn't.  Then the `_mixins.scss` file includes variables defined in `variables` and so on.  None of it in dot notation.  BS just was not written for the `@use` usage.

Comment: ohh now I got it, thanks a lot